# Remove Duplicates from Sorted List -- LeetCode Solution in C

Tags: algorithm, c

Given a sorted linked list, delete all nodes that have duplicate numbers, leaving only distinct numbers from the original list.

For example,
Given 1->2->3->3->4->4->5, return 1->2->5.
Given 1->1->1->2->3, return 2->3.

```
**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
    struct ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head) {
    }
```

---

I have the written the solution for it, but looking for more ideas and suggestions. This solution has passed all the 166 test cases from leetcode.

```
    /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
struct ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head) {
 struct ListNode * current = head, *nextNode, *temp;


 //No elements
 if(head == NULL)
 {
     return NULL;
 }

 //Single element linked list
 if(head->next == NULL)
 {
     return head;
 }

     //if the numbers are repeating from the beginning;;
     //then we need to move head;
     while(head !=NULL && head->next !=NULL && head->val == head->next->val){
     if( head->val == head->next->val)
     {
         nextNode = head->next;
         while(nextNode !=NULL  && head->val == nextNode->val){
            temp = nextNode;
        nextNode = nextNode->next;
            free(temp);
         }

         temp = head;
         head = nextNode;
         current = head;
         free(temp);
     }

     }
     //Again a check to see if the list is empty

         if(head == NULL)
         {
             return NULL;
         }


    while(current->next != NULL){

     nextNode = current->next;



        if(nextNode->next !=NULL  && nextNode->val == nextNode->next->val){         

         while(nextNode->next !=NULL  && nextNode->val == nextNode->next->val){
            temp = nextNode->next;
        nextNode->next = temp->next;
         }
        current->next = nextNode->next;

        }else {
            current = nextNode;   
        }

 }

return head;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple recursive method like this: basically, we only need to care about the previous node and current node when deleting a node.

```
ListNode* deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* head) {
     deleteDuplicates(NULL, head);
     return head;
}

void deleteDuplicates(struct ListNode* pre, struct ListNode* cur) {
   if(cur == NULL)
      return;
   if(pre == NULL){
      deleteDuplicates(cur, cur->next);
   }else if(pre->val == cur->val){//Delete duplicate node
      pre->next = cur->next;
      deleteDuplicates(pre, pre ->next);
   }else{//The current node doesn't need to be deleted, move forward
      deleteDuplicates(cur, cur->next);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. There were 166 test cases. I wanted to pass all of the test cases.
Consider the test case 1,2,3,3,3,4,5 : in this scenario your code will provide me with the
 output: 1,2,3,4,5. But instead 
Expected output is:  1,2,4,5 (removing all the duplicates as per the question)